# Existence of a solution of a quadratic form inequality?

Tags: inequality, quadratic-forms

I am working on a problem that requires me to show whether a solution to the system of equations
$x^T A x > 0$ and $b^T x < 0$ exists or not, for some $x$. It important to note  that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$  and that $b$ and $A$ are known and the question is whether an $x$ exists (so that means that $x$ is unknown) so that both of the conditions ($x^T A x > 0$ and $b^T x < 0$) are satisfied.

Now, I know that if $A$ is positive definite then all non-trivial $x$ satisfy the equation $x^T A x > 0$ or if $A$ is negative definite that no $x$ satisfies the equation $x^T A x > 0$, but what happens in the case where $A$ is neither positive nor negative definite, in addition to that I also have to worry about whether there exists an $x$ that satisfies $x^T A x > 0$ and $b^T x < 0$ simultaneously.

I really have no idea how to approach this problem and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $b^T x > 0$ then $b^T(-x)<0$, while $x^T A x = (-x^T)A (-x)$

Answer (score 1):

If $b=0$ or if $x^T A x \le 0$ for all $x$, there is obviously no solution. Let us now suppose that $b \neq 0$ and $x_0^T A x_0 > 0$ for some $x_0$. Let $x = x_0+ t b$. When $t$ is close enough to $0$ and different from $0$, one has $x^T A x > 0$ and $b^T x = b^T x_0 + t\ b^T b \neq 0$. If $b^T x < 0$, then $x$ is a solution, otherwise $-x$ is a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now the problem is how to find $x_0$.

Comment: You could take an eigenvector for a positive eigenvalue of $A+A^T$

Comment: amazing thank you very much sir

Comment: Okay, so I thought I could use the same analogy in the case where I need to find an $x$ that satisfies $x^T A x > 0$, $x^T B x > 0$, $b_1^T x < 0$ and $b_2^T x < 0$ but that does not seem to be working any hint here? :/

Comment: Sorry I thought I had an idea for this but there was an error in the reasoning.

Comment: thanks for trying maybe you can share your idea and we can try it together.